# Why doesn't insert statement create new rows?

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert

My insert statement should be creating a new row everytime I run it, but it doesn't. It does not hit me with any errors either.

```
    @Override
public void addToDatabase() {
    try {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:8889/Bank", "kculbreth36",
                "Gerder11");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
                .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO budgeting (GrossPay, TakehomePay, Tips) VALUE (?,?,?)");
        pstmt.setDouble(1, gross);
        pstmt.setDouble(2, tax);
        pstmt.setInt(3, tips);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be  VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: @tha07 But no error - strange or false.

Comment: Changed that, still no change on the table though.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling this method?

Comment: In my main i call it like this so im unsure why it doesnt work ` income i = new income();
  i.displayDate();
  i.displayIncome();
  i.addToDatabase();`

Comment: hard code variable values inside the function and try. I don't see any values for the variables here

Comment: Hard coding yielded no result. It calls a nullpointer error on the `PreparedStatement` line though.

Comment: You declare Connection myConn but using conn.prepareStatement. this two has to be equal right?

Comment: @tha07 After changing that it says that field Date does not have a default value.         - ive changed the default value to all the columns in the database to null and changed the conn.close to myConn.close and it has now started to give values, but only for the Tips column, grosspay and takehomepay are input as 0.

Comment: that's because you have a date column in your database table and you don't provide a value when inserting

Comment: ok prob final thing, is it possible to add values to null column in a row. i say this because i am running three classes that add different values into the database and when run, it adds the values from one class and fills null into the columns not given, and then when the next class addstodatabase, it creates a new row and does the same thing for its respective columns.

Comment: Is your connection set to autocommit?  If not, you will need to issue a commit statement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `myConn` as connection, but create a prepared statement with `conn`. So probably your `conn` executes separately and probably or it does not commit (and the connection is not in autocommit mode), or in a separate database schema (you don't provide enough information about it). The fact is that the statement should throw an `SQLException`, because the syntax of the insert statement should be with "`VALUES`" keyword and not "`VALUE`".